# showcasing the leader

Tags: portrait, group-photos

How do you best showcase the "boss" or leader of a professional group in a group shot?
Also, if you have the leader sitting and others standing around them, does that dimish the leader or boss in any way since the leader would be in a lower position?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/54db87f2816608815fd00d81/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/kim-jong-un-north-korea-vf.jpg) or like [that](https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/MSNBC/Components/Slideshows/_production/ss-130212-kim-jong-un/ss-130213-kim-jong-un-04.jpg)? (I do not own any rights on these pictures, and please take this with a bit of humor)

Comment: @MrUpsidown - I see… you mean the leader is the one *not* wearing a hat;) Seriously, though it does raise the question of 'how formal is this group of people?' Are we're talking 'Ernst Stavro Blofeld + minions', or a single department of graphic designers?

Comment: @Tetsujin Absolutely, yes! It works though in these 2 examples as you instantly figure out who *the leader* is. But maybe it's not just the hat ;) I agree it depends on the group of people / the relation between the leader and the rest of the group (and the relation you want to convey in your image) / how you feature that lower position and how it will *feel* in the final image.

Comment: Movies make the leader taller and bigger, usually more in the foreground. You can make them brighter as well. Sitting in a chair where everyone else stands conveys importance, despite being opposite of the boss=taller rule, because of how so many group photographs have been taken, it has it's own constructed meaning.

Comment: Kings hold court sitting on thrones. Their subjects must appear before the King standing or kneeling on the floor.

Comment: This question probably needs to qualify the context of what culture it's asking about. I can imagine it might be quite different from one culture to another. Are we talking about Western Europe/North America? South Asia? Pacific Islanders? Etc.